# Unable to create cornor radius on UIView previewLayer of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to create below view on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer of camera,

[image]

My code,

```
CGFloat frameWidth = self.bounds.size.width - 2 * self.frameOffset;
if (!self.dataReadingFrame) {
    self.dataReadingFrame = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, self.frameHeight)]; //
    self.dataReadingFrame.center = self.center;
    self.dataReadingFrame.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self createCustomFramesForView:self.dataReadingFrame];
    [self addSubview:self.dataReadingFrame];
    
    [self startAnimatingScanner:self.dataReadingFrame];
    
    [self addVisualEffects:self.dataReadingFrame.frame];
    
    CGRect visibleRect = [self.previewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:self.dataReadingFrame.frame];
    self.metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = visibleRect;
    self.previewLayer.cornerRadius = 20;

- (void)createCustomFramesForView:(UIView *)frameView {
    CGFloat cornerSize = 40.f;
    CGFloat cornerWidth = 4.f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        CGFloat x = 0.0;
        CGFloat y = 0.0;
        CGFloat width = 0.0;
        CGFloat height = 0.0;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                x = 0; y = 0; width = cornerWidth; height = cornerSize;
                break;
            case 1:
                x = 0; y = 0; width = cornerSize; height = cornerWidth;
                break;
            case 2:
                x = CGRectGetWidth(frameView.bounds) - cornerSize; y = 0; width = cornerSize; height = cornerWidth;
                break;
            case 3:
                x = CGRectGetWidth(frameView.bounds) - cornerWidth; y = 0; width = cornerWidth; height = cornerSize;
                break;
            case 4:
                x = CGRectGetWidth(frameView.bounds) - cornerWidth;
                y = CGRectGetHeight(frameView.bounds) - cornerSize; width = cornerWidth; height = cornerSize;
                break;
            case 5:
                x = CGRectGetWidth(frameView.bounds) - cornerSize;
                y = CGRectGetHeight(frameView.bounds) - cornerWidth; width = cornerSize; height = cornerWidth;
                break;
            case 6:
                x = 0; y = CGRectGetHeight(frameView.bounds) - cornerWidth; width = cornerSize; height = cornerWidth;
                break;
            case 7:
                x = 0; y = CGRectGetHeight(frameView.bounds) - cornerSize; width = cornerWidth; height = cornerSize;
                break;
        }
        UIView * cornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        cornerView.backgroundColor = self.frameColor;
        cornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
        [frameView addSubview:cornerView];
    }
}
```

Above code output looks like below,
[image]

Above image is edited because i unable to attach real pic from iOS device, but output is look similar.
Even I tried to draw bezier curve but same output.